# NotificationCompat doesn't contains InboxStyle

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm developing an android application using support v4 api and ActionBarSherlock library.

I need to show a list of events inside an notification. The android developer site shows an example using the NotificationCompat.InboxStyle, however, my support v4 api appears not to have this class. I'm using the newest version (rev. 18).

Anyone already had this problem?

Comment: It resolves for me just fine. How have you determined that your JAR does not have the class?

Comment: I just found out that the supportv4 in the ActionBarSherlock library was outdated. I updated it and now it works fine.